# Non-Ascii chars saved as '?' when using JPA in Google App Engine Development Environment

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, jpa, eclipselink, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using JPA (EclipseLink implementation) to build a Google Cloud Endpoints API on top of Google Cloud SQL.
When I insert, through that API, strings with non-ascii characters (i.e. Hebrew or Arabic) it works fine in the deployed application on Google App Engine, but on my local Java Development Server these characters are saved as '?'. 
When I use a 'regular' servlet  to access the same database tables and insert the same strings (obtaining the database connection with DriverManager.getConnection()) everything works fine, so it cannot be a problem with my local database settings.

I use (both for the servlet and the JPA based implementation) "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" and my connection URL is

```
"jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/guestbook?user=root&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

I have the following entries in my appengine-web.xml file:

```
<property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="DEFAULT_ENCODING" value="UTF-8" />
```

and both character_set_server and character_set_database are set to utf8 on my local server.

Here is my code for inserting the strings into the database:

```
public class Guestbook {
private static     Map<String, String> properties; 
private static     EntityManagerFactory emf;

static{
    properties = new HashMap();

      properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver",
          "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url",
             "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/guestbook?user=root&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8");

    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
        "Demo", properties);

}
@ApiMethod(name = "greetings.insert", httpMethod = "post")
  public void insertEntry(GuestEntry entry) {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(new GuestEntry(entry.getMessage()));
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any clue?

Comment: there is a missing question mark in your mysql connection url: typo?

Comment: yes typo here - fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, it's only dev server console that can not show UTF-8 chars. Otherwise data is saved just fine.

Comment: I am using mysql not the datastore, so I think that the dev server console is not relevant for viewing data in this case. In the mysql client I can put in non-ascii string manually through insert queries and it works fine, if I insert through the endpoints/JPA they are created with '?' characters